# How to check if variables are true with in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to call these arrays and check if the whole array is true (like ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"]). I have my HTML and JS below.

This will probably be pretty easy for someone to fix, I am just struggling to find any stuff about and how to fix it.

```
<tr>
            <td id="cell1" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell2" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell3" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="cell4" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell5" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell6" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="cell7" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell8" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell9" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
        </tr>

var win = [
            ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
            ["cell1", "cell4", "cell7"],
            ["cell1", "cell5", "cell9"],
            ["cell2", "cell5", "cell8"],
            ["cell3", "cell6", "cell9"],
            ["cell3", "cell5", "cell7"],
            ["cell4", "cell5", "cell6"],
            ["cell7", "cell8", "cell9"]
        ];

        function tic(element) {
            element.textContent = "X";

            for (i = 0; i < win.length; i++) { 
                var thisWinningCombo = win[i];

                for (x = 0; x < thisWinningCombo.length; x++) { 
                    var cellId = thisWinningCombo[x];
                    var cellValue = document.getElementById(cellId).textContent;
                    console.log(cellId + ": " + cellValue);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve? The hasWon variable is set to true if one of the winning combos is found

```js
var win = [
            ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
            ["cell1", "cell4", "cell7"],
            ["cell1", "cell5", "cell9"],
            ["cell2", "cell5", "cell8"],
            ["cell3", "cell6", "cell9"],
            ["cell3", "cell5", "cell7"],
            ["cell4", "cell5", "cell6"],
            ["cell7", "cell8", "cell9"]
        ];

        function tic(element) {
            element.textContent = "X";

            for (i = 0; i < win.length; i++) { 
                var thisWinningCombo = win[i];
                var hasWon = true;
                for (x = 0; x < thisWinningCombo.length; x++) { 
                    var cellId = thisWinningCombo[x];
                    var cellValue = document.getElementById(cellId).textContent;
                    //console.log(cellId + ": " + cellValue);
                    hasWon = hasWon && (cellValue == "X");
                }
                if (hasWon){
                  console.log(hasWon);
                }

            }
        }
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
            <td id="cell1" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell2" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell3" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="cell4" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell5" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell6" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="cell7" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell8" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
            <td id="cell9" onclick="tic(this)"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```